# Ubuntu 19.10 - Dual screen support with Ubuntu 19.10 and Windows 10 laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors, laptop, windows-10

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 19.10 installed also another laptop with windows 10. Can I uses the Windows 10 laptop as secondary screen for laptop with Ubuntu ? Is this possible over LAN/HDMI cable ? or any other options ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Synergy Program https://symless.com/synergy
Share one mouse and keyboard between multiple computers(Mac, Linux, Windows)